# Can virtual reality goggles have focal point 20 feet away?

Tags: optics

Can virtual reality goggles have focal point 20 feet away?

I read that eye strain from computer screens occurs if the eyes spend too much time looking at a screen that is too close.

The 20-20-20 rule states that you should look away from your computer screen 20 feet for 20 seconds every 20 minutes.

Are there any virtual reality goggles that could project a screen 20 feet into the distance but still with elements big enough to easily see?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it exists, but there's no reason it couldn't.  A simple diverging lens system could be used to make a virtual image of a close-in display appear at 20 feet.

The more difficult problem would be making different portions of the display have their virtual images at different distances (presumably one that corresponded with the intended distance of the displayed object).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is about the same as wearing reading glasses in that in either case you are wearing an appliance. Correctly prescribed reading glasses create a relaxed reading environment

The real challenge is to create a computer/mobile phone screen that acts as if you are looking into the distance ie infinity focal length. That way older people with good distance sight, who rely on reading specs for closer vision, would be able to see clearly without needing to wear any appliance
Younger people who tire easily following near work would not need to accommodate (ie focus their eyes)  It is the accommodation required at near distances that often causes eye strain
to develop